# How to render same component multiple time in material dialog in angular 10+?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular10

Component: OpenMultiTimeComponent

selector: 'open-multi-time'

Need Solution for following situtation,

1. Open dialog - load **OpenMultiTimeComponent** component.
2. Open another dialog - load **TestComponent** component.
3. Open **OpenMultiTimeComponent** inside **TestComponent**.

```
<mat-dialog>  // Dialog 1
  <open-multi-time></open-multi-time> // Ref: 1

  <TestComponent> // Dialog 2
    <mat-dialog> 
      <open-multi-time></open-multi-time> // Ref: 2
    </mat-dialog>  
  </TestComponent> 
 
</mat-dialog>
```

Problem:

- When i update any variable from Ref: 2 component then it will update same variable from Ref: 1. *This is an issue.*

We don't want to update that variable from Ref:1 component. We required an unique component for Ref:1 & Ref:2.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding new dialog component for the nested dialog, Because you are trying to open same dialog box. Because if the component remain same then the member variables would share the same behavior.

Comment: Can we update selector name dynamically ?

Comment: No you cannot update your selector name. Rule is one component one static selector. Because you selector is responsible to load the component, if you trying to do such changes, then it would stop loading the component.

Comment: you might use some custom input variables to run your logic inside component instead of changing the whole selector